# DHCP service and network manager issues after reinstalling KDE in Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I've reinstalled KDE on Kubuntu 23.04, while trying to fix errors with nVidia 525 driver.
I've reinstalled kde-plasma-desktop, and nvidia drivers and the open source drivers worked, but I've experienced some errors with KDE, I've fixed them by installing missing packages.
The only error that I'm still experiencing is a problem with network:
If I turn on the computer the DHCP service doesn't start automatically.
When I do the command `sudo dhclient -v` the network works fine, but I still have no avaliable connections message in KDE Network Manager (before bug I've a proper ethernet profile). Connection menu in system settings is also empty.

[image: Network manager view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by reinstalling KDE and installing kde full.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kde-full
```